# Tile a square with five rectangles with 10 distinct edges

Tags: geometry, dissection, tiling

The baby brother of: [Cutting a square into seven rectangles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23832/cutting-a-square-into-seven-rectangles)

Tile a square with five rectangles. Select the lengths of the edges of the rectangles from the set $1$ through $10$, with no length repeated.

Find all possible tilings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the solutions

> In each example, the dimensions of each rectangle are listed vertical side first. 
>  Square has side length $13$ [image] 
>  Square has side length $13$ [image] 
>  Square has side length $11$ [image] 
>  Square has side length $11$ [image]

I think that, up to rotations and reflections, these are the only solutions.

Comment: Yup that's all of them.